# Flutter Firebase changing widget after loging

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I created bool parameter and I am passing it from `auth.dart` to `wrapper.dart`. Parameter changes its value after loging/registering and signing out - **false** should return in `wrapper.dart` Loging widget and **true** should return HomePage widget. But `wrapper.dart` only reads *authorised's* value at the start, and even if it changes, Wrapper does nothing. Any idea how to solve it?

**auth.dart:**

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  bool authorised = true;

  //Registering with email and password
  void register(String email, String password) async {
    final FirebaseUser user = (
        await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
    ).user;
    authorised = true;
    print(authorised);
  }

  //Logging with email and password
  void login(String email, String password) async {
    final FirebaseUser user = (
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
    ).user;
    authorised = true;
    print(authorised);
  }

  //Signing out
  void signOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
    authorised = false;
    print(authorised);
  }
}
```

**wrapper.dart:**

```
class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  AuthService authService = AuthService();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return authService.authorised ? HomePage() : Registering();
  }
}
```

I have also tried doing `if(user != null){...}` in **auth.dart** and `if(authService.authorised = true){return HomePage();}` in **wrapper.dart**, but it also doesn't work :/

Comment: You need to look into streams. Here is an article to get you started. https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/super-simple-authentication-flow-with-flutter-firebase-737bba04924c

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream-class.html